# Remove number of li by loop with certain number in jquery

Tags: jquery

On button click I have to remove a certain number of `li` only. Every time  the button is clicked the number of `li` to remove will change. How can I achieve this? I have multiple `li` like this:

```
<li class="sc-item"></li>
<li class="sc-item"></li>
<li class="sc-item"></li>
<li class="sc-item"></li>
<li class="sc-item"></li>
<li class="sc-item"></li>
<li class="sc-item"></li>
```

This will give me the count of `li`:

```
var licount = $("#ullist li").length;
```

Comment: what have you tried? put your test code.

Comment: Where is your button click logic? How do you calculate which `li` should be removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried myself to remove no.of li

```
                var licount = $(".ul li").length;
                for (i = 0; i < count2rmv; i++) {
                    $(".ul li").eq(i).remove();
                }
```

anyway thanks guys :)